# Python Function That Counts Number of Alphabetic Characters, Keeps Track of How Many Times "e" Appears

Tags: python, string, function, testing, character

Write a function analyze_text that receives a string as input. The function should count the number of alphabetic characters (a through z, or A through Z) in the text and also keep track of how many are the letter 'e' (upper or lowercase).

The function should return an analysis of the text, something like this:

The text contains 240 alphabetic characters, of which 105 (43.75%) are ‘e’.

I need to make use of the isalpha function, which can be used like this:

```
"a".isalpha() # => evaluates to True
"3".isalpha() # => evaluates to False
"&".isalpha() # => False
" ".isalpha() # => False

mystr = "Q"
mystr.isalpha() # => True
```

The function should pass the following tests:

```
from test import testEqual

text1 = "Eeeee"
answer1 = "The text contains 5 alphabetic characters, of which 5 
(100.0%) are 'e'."

testEqual(analyze_text(text1), answer1)

text2 = "Blueberries are tasteee!"
answer2 = "The text contains 21 alphabetic characters, of which 7
(33.3333333333%) are 'e'."

testEqual(analyze_text(text2), answer2)

text3 = "Wright's book, Gadsby, contains a total of 0 of that most
common symbol ;)"

answer3 = "The text contains 55 alphabetic characters, of which 0
(0.0%) are 'e'."

testEqual(analyze_text(text3), answer3)
```

So I tried:

```
def analyze_text(text):

    text = input("Enter some text")
    alphaChars = len(text)

#count the number of times "e" appears
    eChars = text.count('e')

#find percentage that "e" appears
    eCharsPercent = eChars / alphaChars

    print("The text contains" + alphaChars + "alphabetic characters, of 
    which" + eChars + "(" + eCharsPercent + ") are 'e'.")

from test import testEqual

text1 = "Eeeee"
answer1 = "The text contains 5 alphabetic characters, of which 5
(100.0%) are 'e'."

testEqual(analyze_text(text1), answer1)

text2 = "Blueberries are tasteee!"
answer2 = "The text contains 21 alphabetic characters, of which 7
(33.3333333333%) are 'e'."

testEqual(analyze_text(text2), answer2)

text3 = "Wright's book, Gadsby, contains a total of 0 of that most
common symbol ;)"
answer3 = "The text contains 55 alphabetic characters, of which 0
(0.0%) are 'e'."

testEqual(analyze_text(text3), answer3)
```

As you can see, what I tried doesn't make use of the isalpha function (I don't know how / where to use it). Also, the function won't return whether or not the tests were passed. Visualize python doesn't support "test", and the text editor that I'm using in the book says that I have an indentation error (?) I don't know where to start - please help.

[Screenshot of Book Text Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qnKL.png)

**EDIT**: Now receiving "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects on line 12" (the line that starts with "print").

Comment: in analyse_text the print statement is on 2 lines without a backslash. Here's one of your errors...

Comment: Indentation error means you didn't indent your code correctly. As Python uses indentation instead of braces ({, }) to group blocks, you need to make sure you use spaces and tabs correctly. Don't mix tabs and spaces, and always use the same amount of tabs/spaces.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you're right I was missing a ")". I fixed that, and now I'm receiving a new error message: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects on line 12. That's the line that starts with "print".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an `analyse_text` function that passes the tests:

```
def analyze_text(text):
    filtered = [c.lower() for c in text if c.isalpha()]
    cnt = filtered.count('e')
    result = "The text contains {} alphabetic characters, of which {} ({}%) are 'e'.".format(len(filtered),cnt,str(100.0*cnt/len(filtered))[:13])
    return result
```

- create a list of all alphanum chars, lowercase, using a nice list comprehension (that's the part you were missing), creates `filtered` variable
- count letter `e` (you got that right), creates `cnt` counter
- format string accordignly (used a bit of a hack to get the `33.3333333` right, maybe something better can be done). Getting the exact string is a bit pointless..., creates `result` string that is returned the line after

Comment: Since I'm just learning python (and coding), analyze_text is a function name - but what are "filtered", "cnt", and "result"? Variables? Besides that your answer makes sense, thanks.

Comment: I am running into a problem with your hack when I submit the assignment....the result needs to return 5 more digits to match the solution exactly. See this screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/6zi5e2c.jpg

Comment: Never mind I was able to figure it out - changed your splice from [:13] to [:18] to force 5 more digits. Thanks.

Comment: I explained the variables more, see my edit. Glad it worked for ya.